# How to implement persistent page using php/jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, persistent

You load a page display.php with a lot of ajax content in different areas of page.
A user clicks inside the page and some part of ajax content changes. Now when a user
clicks the reload button on the browser it will loose the content loaded from ajax requests.

How do I retain all information loaded by ajax? Much Thanks.

Comment: You could store the data in a session.

Comment: I was hoping someone had made a library already for this function. I guess one option is the one @krister-andersson Suggested or store in database all events happening on that ajax content/widgets and associate with the current user.

Comment: Combination of session and [hashbang uri](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html). (Basically use hash tag to symbolize which URL the client is visiting making it easily re-referenced/recallable)

Comment: I'm using a clean uri @Brad  i'm thinking by storing 'controller/method/param/value' in a session with key assign to that ajax container will do the trick. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- store information in [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) (in JavaScript),
- store information on the server, eg. using **server sessions**,

plus one additional possibility (if applicable in your case):

- use **[`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) and [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate)** to support URL changes without requests to the server (alternatively solve it with [**`onhashchange`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange)),

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [location hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp).
Write something on the location hash as an ajax call runs. So when you reload the page, the on `$(document).ready` you may read that hash and load the data again with ajax calls.

This approach has a point, you can share the url#hash as a link to that data with other persons. It's not dependent to your `session` or your `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Krister has it right. Store the changes in a session variable and have a recall function on $(document).ready that checks session variables. ;)